# Powershell Get-Childitem exclude sub directory with in a directory

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have my folder structure as follows

```
D:\Exclude
     Include
     Include1
         Exclude
         Include
```

What I need is I would like to filter the directory `Include1\Exclude` this is what I tried which is not working

```
$Path ="D:\Exclude"
$DirList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path" -Recurse | where {$_.DirectoryName -ne "D:\Exclude\Include1\Exclude"}
$DirList
```

Comment: Do your folder names really like Exclude and include?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.FullName` property instead of Directory name, like so.

```
 dir $path -Recurse  | measure | select Count

Count
-----
    4

PS C:\users\Stephen> dir $path -Recurse  | ?  FullName -ne "R:\Exclude\Include1\Exclude" |
>> measure | select Count

Count
-----
    3
```

Comment: Note that if you are try to also filter out files in the exclude folder you will need to change it to `FullName -notlike "D:\Exclude\Include1\Exclude*"`

Answer (score 1):

use a like with path of your dir to exclude dir and file

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Exclude" -Recurse | where FullName -NotLike "D:\Exclude\Include1\Exclude\*"


#short version
gci "D:\Exclude" -Rec | ? FullName -NotLike "D:\Exclude\Include1\Exclude\*"
```